# How to get file name when using express.bodyParser

Tags: node.js, file-upload, upload, express

When I use this module `app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: __dirname + "/public/adminupload" }));`.My files are uploaded to `__dirname + "/public/adminupload"` directory but the file name is change randomly, new name is differently with `req.files.file.name`. So how can I get the new name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get entire path from `req.files.file.path`. You can extract the filename like this:

```
path = require('path')
console.log(path.basename(req.files.file.path));
```